# PyCharm - Trailing type hints and line width limit

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

In PyCharm, I typically use trailing [type hints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html) (not sure of the right way of calling them) for variables such as this:

```
my_var = my_other_variable  # type: MyObject
```

However, sometimes I already have a very long line which I cannot really split, or the type hint is a bit long, such as:

```
my_var = my_really_long_variable_name  # type: QtWidgets.QVeryLongQtClassName
```

This would make the full line longer than my line width limit (79 characters), and hence PyCharm would flag a warning.

Hence, **is there a way to put the type hint in a different line?** I tried these but they do not seem to work:

```
# type: QtWidgets.QVeryLongQtClassName
my_var = my_really_long_variable_name

my_var = my_really_long_variable_name \
    # type: QtWidgets.QVeryLongQtClassName
```

The closest thing I can think of is this, which may not really shorten that much the line width:

```
my_var = \
    my_really_long_variable_name  # type: QtWidgets.QVeryLongQtClassName
```

Otherwise, the only alternative I have is to do something like this:

```
v = my_really_long_variable_name
my_var = v  # type: QtWidgets.QVeryLongQtClassName
```

The other alternative of shortening the type does not seem to work based on the tests I have done; PyCharm seems to struggle recognising that `my_var`'s type is really `QtWidgets.QVeryLongQtClassName` in this case:

```
t = QtWidgets.QVeryLongQtClassName
my_var = my_really_long_variable_name  # type: t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it very convenient to import the class names directly from the module for the type annotation usage. For example:

```
from QtWidgets import QVeryLongQtClassName
my_var = my_really_long_variable_name  # type: QVeryLongQtClassName
```

I have not encountered a problem like yours yet with this attitude.

However, I found this version to be the most readable and convenient way to annotate a long line:

```
my_var = \
    my_really_long_variable_name  # type: QtWidgets.QVeryLongQtClassName
```

**UPDATE:** Another way to implement this:

```
my_var = (
    my_really_long_variable_name
)  # type: QtWidgets.QVeryLongQtClassName
```

In addition, it is supported and does not cause problems in most IDEs.

Comment: Your update gave me the idea that you can also put the type hint outside the brackets and PyCharm also seems to recognise it fine. That looks ideal to me, as you then have plenty of space to specify the type hint.I added this option to your question (hope you don't mind)

Comment: Actually, they rejected the edit. Could you add that option yourself and I will re-accept the answer? Otherwise I can also add my own answer quoting yours. Basically, putting the `# type:` annotation after the closing bracket, such as: `)  # type: QtWidgets.QVeryLongQtClassName`

Comment: @FernAndr Edited :)